# how to smoothly tilt or rotate object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a simple helicopter game in unity, the helicopter can tilt but its snaps and not smooth

this is the simple code where it snap tilt

```
   `float tilammount = 13;
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * tilammount);
    }`
```

I tried adding the logic where the helicopter smoothly rotates or orientates itself to the camera, but after adding that, it won't tilt anymore.

```
    float turnsmootht = 0.8f;
    float turnsmvelo;
    //heli orient itself to camera 
    float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, cam.eulerAngles.y, ref turnsmvelo, turnsmootht);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);

    //movement
    float tilammount = 13;
    float tiltsmvelo;
    float tiltsmo = 60f;
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        float tilt = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.x, tilammount, ref tiltsmvelo, tiltsmo);            
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * tilt);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems like you want to smoothly tilt your helicopter while also ensuring it orients itself smoothly to the camera. To achieve this, you can use a combination of `SmoothDampAngle` for both the orientation and the tilt. Thats my option, how u can modify your code ! good luck !

```js
using UnityEngine;

public class HelicopterController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform cam; // Reference to the camera transform
    public float turnSmoothTime = 0.8f;
    public float tiltSmoothTime = 0.6f;
    public float tiltAmount = 13f;

    private float turnSmoothVelocity;
    private float tiltSmoothVelocity;

    private void Update()
    {
        // Helicopter orientation to camera
        float targetAngle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, cam.eulerAngles.y, ref turnSmoothVelocity, turnSmoothTime);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f);

        // Helicopter tilt
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            float targetTilt = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.x, tiltAmount, ref tiltSmoothVelocity, tiltSmoothTime);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(targetTilt, targetAngle, 0f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, but I was only looking for a way to make this "transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * tilammount);" have a smooth rotation, and I was hoping to find other ways to make it work, the part where I use the heli's orientation to the camera was only my idea base on my understanding of SmoothDampAngle, I also applied your option but it did not work, and actually the helicopter always orients itself to the camera even when its tilting so I did not need to ensure that it orients itself, the only problem is it not tilting smoothly, instead it snaps